# Портирование кода с Windows 8.1 на UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Делаю авторизацию через сервисы "Вконтакте" но тамашний код для Windows 8 версии. Первая проблема появилась с Package.appxmanifest
При добавлении расширения возникают неполадки... Как это можно исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так что за ошибка то?

Comment: @Grundy не то чтобы ошибки, просто не дает добавить эту часть кода (Extensions, см скриншот)